# Nifi - Route the JSON based on the Array Name

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi, i hv a requirement where we get multiple JSON inputs with different Header Names. I have to parse the JSON and insert into different tables based on the Header value.

Not sure how to use RouteonContent processor or EvaluateJSON Path processor

Input 1

```
{
  "Location": [
    {
      "country": "US",
      "division": "Central",
      "region": "Big South",
      "locationID": 1015,
      "location_name": "Hattiesburg, MS (XF)",
      "location_type": "RETAIL",
      "location_sub_type": "COS",
      "store_type": "",
      "planned_open_date": "",
      "planned_close_date": "",
      "actual_open_date": "2017-07-26",
      "actual_close_date": "",
      "new_store_flag": "",
      "address1": "2100 Lincoln Road",
      "address2": "",
      "city": "Hattiesburg",
      "state": "MS",
      "zip": 39402,
      "include_for_planning": "Y"
    },
    {
      "country": "US",
      "division": "Central",
      "region": "Big South",
      "locationID": 1028,
      "location_name": "Laurel, MS",
      "location_type": "RETAIL",
      "location_sub_type": "COS",
      "store_type": "",
      "planned_open_date": "",
      "planned_close_date": "",
      "actual_open_date": "",
      "actual_close_date": "",
      "new_store_flag": "",
      "address1": "1225 5th street",
      "address2": "",
      "city": "Laurel",
      "state": "MS",
      "zip": 39440,
      "include_for_planning": "Y"
    }
]
```

Input 2

```
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "npi_code": "NEW",
      "cifa_category": "XM",
      "o9_category": "Accessories"
    },
{
      "npi_code": "NEW",
      "cifa_category": "XM0",
      "o9_category": "Accessories"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the website https://jsonpath.com/ to figure out the proper JSON expression. But what you could potentially do is use: if the array contains either $.npi_code then do X and if it contains $. country, then do Y